# numpy.fft(): custom range of frequencies

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am loading audio signals with `librosa.load()`, which are available as an array of the time as as a signal values.

For this audio signal I want to determine the `FFT with numpy.fft()`:

```
y,sr = librosa.load(audio_file, sr=None)
X = fft(y)
N = len(X)
n = np.arange(N)
T = N/sr
freq = n/T
```

Is there a way to manipulate the frequency range so that the frequency steps are each a multiple of `1,000 Hz`?  Or is this only possible by resampling or extending the audio signal? What are the risks of resampling?

Comment: my guess is you can do what you suggest or force the hand upstream by setting the sample count fed into the fft call such that the frequency increment between each element of the array returned from the fft call matches some value ( 1 kHz )  ... incr_freq := sample_rate / number_of_samples  //  with sample_rate of 44100 samples per second, and one second worth of samples ( 44100 ) this gives you a frequency increment resolution of 1 Hertz ... IE each freq bin is 1 Hertz apart

Comment: You can either pad and resample the data so you get the desired spacing in the frequency domain; or you can not use the FFT and instead directly compute the correlation with complex sinusoids of the desired set of frequencies.